# Drag & Drop between to List with Custom ListItem

Tags: drag-and-drop, qooxdoo

i have multiple Lists with Custom ListItems (All of them have the same) and i want to have them sortable and be able to Drag & Drop them to another list.

All of this workes fine, but when i select a Droped ListItem i get an Exception that the item is not child of this widget. Also when i call the indexOf Method on the list with the listItem i get -1.

So when i call getChildren on the list (before and after the insert) the Element is in the list and the view also render it correctly even the selection!

Here is the code of my List:

```
qx.Class.define("padawan.quicksearch.SearchList", {
extend : qx.ui.form.List,

construct : function() {
    this.base(arguments);
    this.context = arguments[0];

    this.setHeight(null);

    this.setEnableInlineFind(false);

    this.setDroppable(true);
    this.setDraggable(true);

    // create the controller
    var controller = new qx.data.controller.List(null, this);
    controller.setDelegate({
        createItem : function() {
            return new padawan.quicksearch.SucheComposite(this.context);
        },
        bindItem : function(controller, item, id) {
            controller.bindProperty("", "model", null, item, id);
        }
    });

    // Create drag indicator
    var indicator = new qx.ui.core.Widget();
    indicator.setDecorator(new qx.ui.decoration.Decorator().set({
        widthTop : 1,
        styleTop : "solid",
        colorTop : "black"
    }));
    indicator.setHeight(0);
    indicator.setOpacity(0.5);
    indicator.setZIndex(100);
    indicator.setLayoutProperties({
        left : -1000,
        top : -1000
    });
    indicator.setDroppable(true);
    qx.core.Init.getApplication().getRoot().add(indicator);

    // Just add a move action
    this.addListener("dragstart", function(e) {
        var item = this.getSucheComposite(e.getOriginalTarget());

        if (!item) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

        e.addType("items");
        e.addAction("move");
    });

    this.addListener("droprequest", function(e) {
      e.addData("items", [e.getDragTarget()]);
    }, this);

    this.addListener("dragend", function(e) {
        // Move indicator away
        indicator.setDomPosition(-1000, -1000);
    });

    this.addListener("drag", function(e) {
        var orig = e.getOriginalTarget();

        // if (!qx.ui.core.Widget.contains(this, orig) && orig != indicator)
        // {
        // return;
        // }

        var origCoords = orig.getContentLocation();

        indicator.setWidth(orig.getBounds().width);
        indicator.setDomPosition(origCoords.left, origCoords.top);
    });

    this.addListener("drop", function(e) {
        var selection = e.getData("items")[0];
        this.__reorderList(selection, e.getOriginalTarget(), e.getTarget());
    }, this);
},

members : {
    getSucheComposite : function(child) {
        if (child.classname == "padawan.quicksearch.SucheComposite")
            return child;

        while (child) {
            child = child.getLayoutParent();

            if ("padawan.quicksearch.SucheComposite" == child.classname) {
                return child;
            }
        }

        return child;
    },

    __reorderList : function(selection, target, list) {
        selection = this.getSucheComposite(selection);
        if (target.classname !== "padawan.quicksearch.SucheComposite" || !selection) {
            return;
        }

        switch(this.context.type){
        case 'Zeile':
            selection.setIsFilter(false);
            selection.setIsRow(true);
            selection.setIsColumn(false);
            break;
        case 'Filter':
            selection.setIsFilter(true);
            selection.setIsRow(false);
            selection.setIsColumn(false);
            break;
        case 'Spalte':
            selection.setIsFilter(false);
            selection.setIsRow(false);
            selection.setIsColumn(true);
            break;
        }

        list.addBefore(selection, target);
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake by me, i forgot to update the context for the listItem.